# Transposing Data in Pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, python-3.5, transpose

I have an excel file that contains a count of how many times an Part has been used during its lifespan. The data is currently stored in such a way that the Serial numbers are in Column A, and each "Lifespan" Count is stored in adjacent columns, with a "Date" value as its heading.
Here is an example:

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsoEq.png)

I want to be able to pivot/transpose ALL of the Date columns in Python so that the output is in the following format with the Lifespan Count as a new column named "Count":

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ25R.png)

I've tried using the pivot function in pandas to flip the appropriate rows & columns around, however the problem is that I'd have to define each column one at a time. The nature of the spreadsheet used in this example is just one of several spreadsheets I use that all start at a different Date (some start at 01/01/2010 to present while others start at 01/01/1999 to present). It is worth noting that all spreadsheets start at the first of every month and increment 1 month at a time. 
Therefore is there a way I can just select ALL the columns I've loaded into a Dataframe via the spreadsheet loaded to be able to Pivot/Transpose the data as mentioned?

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Serial'], values=['01/01/2019','01/02/2019',... etc], aggfunc='max'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use of `stack()` if you have *named* your column series and have `set_index()` on your rows.

```
import datetime as dt
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({**{"Serial":[s for s in range(1111,1121)]}, 
 **{d:[random.randint(0,150) for i in range(10)] for d in pd.date_range(start=dt.date(2019,1,1), end=dt.date(2019,1,6))}
}).set_index("Serial")
df.columns.set_names("Date", inplace=True)
dfs = df.stack().to_frame().rename(columns={0:"Count"})

print(f"{df.iloc[:,:3].to_string()}\n\n{dfs.iloc[:10].to_string()}")
```

**sample output**

```
Date    2019-01-01 00:00:00  2019-01-02 00:00:00  2019-01-03 00:00:00
Serial                                                               
1111                    134                   76                    8
1112                    115                   37                    8
1113                     16                   23                  130
1114                    108                   45                   69
1115                      0                   51                  111
1116                     51                   71                  101
1117                    107                   10                  142
1118                     80                   48                  134
1119                    148                   62                   75
1120                      4                  135                  100

                            Count
Serial Date                      
1111   2019-01-01 00:00:00    134
       2019-01-02 00:00:00     76
       2019-01-03 00:00:00      8
       2019-01-04 00:00:00     16
       2019-01-05 00:00:00    140
       2019-01-06 00:00:00     28
1112   2019-01-01 00:00:00    115
       2019-01-02 00:00:00     37
       2019-01-03 00:00:00      8
       2019-01-04 00:00:00     56
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, although I should've pointed out that I don't have access to either "datetime" or "random" libraries. The nature of my environment is limited to the default libraries of 3.5.2. Also the Serial numbers are non-sequential, I just used random ones in the example. 
Could this not be achieved via pandas or numpy?

Comment: You don't need either...  you provided sample data as an image so that meant I had to generate it.  To generate it I used `datetime` and `random` as there was no data to paste from you

Comment: there's absolutely no constraint on serial numbers being sequential

Comment: Wow... didn't know that thanks for the idea! How do I stop pandas from auto formatting the column to a datetime value? I'd like it to stay in the format as in Excel ("01/01/2010" instead of "2010-01-01 00:00:00").

Comment: Also I don't think I can use F strings in 3.5.2 can i?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html you can always use this.  I thinks it's a really bad idea as it stops you using date/time functionality

Comment: again f-strings aren't needed in solution....   it's just a convenience for me to paste output back into stackoverflow so that formatting works in html code block !

Comment: there's a clear take away for you - make sure when you ask a question don't expect contributors to do all the leg work to re-produce you scenario and use tech you don't have access to

Comment: No problem, fully understand the comments about expectations as this is a learning platform anyway. Thanks so much!